# Manga where the main character is transmigrated to a movie world, gains a system, and becomes a dryad

Tags: story-identification, manga

In this manga, the main character is transmigrated into a movie world. He also has power that grows stronger as he grows older. He then gets a system and gets transmigrated to different worlds. In one world, he is a dryad.

Answer (score 1):

It's *I Am the King*, aka *打爆诸天* or *Blow Up the Heavens* (Google Translate).

[image: Front cover of I Am the King]

(description sourced from site that infringes copyright, so cannot be named or linked)

> In order to return to his hometown, the Earth, Gao Miao the traverser, journeys through the IP worlds of novels, comics, movies, etc. Experiencing a variety of different lives, getting to know a bunch of beautiful women, and beating up strong enemies.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you could provide a summary, or at least the blurb, and a link to a reference about it.

Comment: I couldn't find a non-infringing link

Comment: Don't forget to come back in 46 hours or so to accept your answer by clicking on the checkmark. :)